How to include time and unit fixed effects in a mediation model using R?
I'm trying to get the indirect effects of the mediation variables m1, m2, and m3 in my dependent variable "y". But also considering the effect of the independent variable "iv" on each of these mediation variables and on the dependent variable.
The models I'm considering are:
m1 = a*iv
m2 = d*iv
Where a and d are the coefficient estimates for iv in model 1 and model 2.
My last model is:
y = civ + bm1 + e*m2
Since I have a panel data set, I would like to include unit (represented by the id variable) and time (represented by the year variable) fixed effects. However, I haven't been able to include them. I looked at many references, but I'm still not able to do it. Here are some of the references I used:
Reference1
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355162153_A_Closer_Look_at_Random_and_Fixed_Effects_Panel_Regression_in_Structural_Equation_Modeling_Using_Lavaan
Reference2
Fixed effect and random intercept models using "lavaan" in R: advice on coding
Here is my code (excluding unsuccessful attempts to incorporate time and unit fixed effects):
library(lavaan)
library(semPlot)

set.seed(123)

n_obs <- 5
n_ids <- 10

dat <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:n_ids, each = n_obs),
  year = rep(2010:2014, times = n_ids),
  y = rnorm(n_obs * n_ids, mean = 100, sd = 10),
  m1 = rnorm(n_obs * n_ids, mean = 50, sd = 5),
  m2 = rnorm(n_obs * n_ids, mean = 30, sd = 3),
  m3 = rnorm(n_obs * n_ids, mean = 20, sd = 2),
  iv = rnorm(n_obs * n_ids, mean = 1000, sd = 53),
  weight = runif(n_obs * n_ids, min = 0.5, max = 2)
)

mediation_model <- '
  # Direct effects
  m1 ~ a * iv
  m2 ~ d * iv
  y  ~ c * iv    +     b * m1  +  e * m2

  # Indirect effect (a * b) + (d * e)
  indirect1 := a * b 
  indirect2 :=d * e

  # Total effect (c + indirect1 + indirect2)
  total := c + indirect1 + indirect2

  #Direct effect
  direct := c
'
mediation_results <- sem(mediation_model, data = dat)

Any help is super appreciated!!!

You would need to create the dummy codes yourself: https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cat.html#exogenous-categorical-variables

Thanks, @Terrence. It worked perfectly. Do you know by any chance if there is a way to include the Driscoll and Kraay (1998) standard errors by using the lavaan package? I'm running each regression "by hand" using the Driscoll and Kraay (1998) standard errors and the results are pretty different from when not using them. But I don't know how to include the  Driscoll and Kraay (1998) methodology into the analysis that is made by the lavaan package.
Many thanks!
